# Password authenticated failed + Docker + Django

Tags: python, django, docker

Not my first time using Docker but obviously I am doing something wrong with my setup that I can't figure out.

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"
services:
   db:
     image: postgres:9.6.9-alpine
     environment:
         POSTGRES_USER: rentalapp
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: rentalapp
         POSTGRES_DB: rentalapp
     ports:
        - "5432:5432"
     volumes:
        - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

And here's my local.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
       "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
       "USER": "rentalapp",
       "PASSWORD": "rentalapp",
       "PORT": 5432,
       "NAME": "rentalapp",
       "HOST": "localhost",
       "ATOMIC_REQUESTS": True,
 }
}
```

Traceback:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "rentalapp"
```

Comment: Where is the user creation? Can you please show the output of '\du' from postgres bash and list out the users ?

Comment: Postgres is not installed locally but within Docker so I don't know if it can be accessed from the terminal directly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess at this bug is that it is to do with volume(bind mount dir).

> It might be because the volume (or bind mount directory) being already
>   initialized after your first start. The postgres user, and database
>   creation only happens on the first start (ie, /var/lib/postgresql/data
>   must not already contain database files). Try to run:

`docker-compose rm -fv postgres` to delete any containers or volumes (in particular).

`docker-compose up -d` to start your container.

Comment: I guessed so too. I have removed the container multiple times and but it issue persists

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51122095/6505847) help?

Comment: I have no entrypoint.sh or Dockerfile so I don't think it will

Answer (score 0):

I figured I had another docker volume and container running.

I decided to resolve it by removing all containers and volumes using [this](https://github.com/Radu-Raicea/Dockerized-Flask/wiki/%5BDocker%5D-Remove-all-Docker-volumes-to-delete-the-database)